# Keep both source .docx filename and comments data when using docxtractr

Tags: r

I have a 1000-row dataframe (read in from a CSV file). Each row has 1 .docx path+filename in one column, and metadata for that document in other columns. I need to extract the COMMENTS from the .docx files, then attach the filename and metadata for the source .docx to each extracted comment row. End goal is a tidy dataframe.

I can extract and aggregate comments for all 1000 files listed in the .docx filenames column via 'docxtractr' using:

```
> document_contents_list <- lapply(file_comments_subset$filename_long, read_docx)
> comments_list <- lapply(document_contents_list, docx_extract_all_cmnts, include_text=TRUE)
> comments_list_joined <- bind_rows(comments_list, .id=NULL)
```

Files are processed and joined as expected, but I lose .docx filenames at the extraction step. So there is no way to identify the source file and reattach meta-data.

Each document has a different number of comments, so reattaching filenames at every nth row via 'cbind' is not an option. Extracting individual lists via 'map_chr' or similar commands is not giving me anything useful so far either. Corpus tools all target the body text of .docx files, not comments, so that is not an option either (best I can tell). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to pass a named `list` and then specify the `.id` in `map`

```
library(purrr)
map_dfr(set_names(document_contents_list, file_comments_subset$filename_long), 
    docx_extract_all_cmnts, include_text=TRUE, .id = 'name')
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Knew it had to be no more than 1-2 lines to make this work. Many thanks.